# how to pass value from visual force page (InputField) to controller?

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, scheduled-apex, dynamic-visualforce

I have created a Vf page from which i need to fetch the value of new owner and need to save the value in property defined in controller:

Following is my vf page code:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:InputField label="user" value="{!a.ownerid}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

here a is object of opportunity

Controller code:

used one property to store the value:

```
public string ownername {get;set;}
```

Note: user will input the value through lookup field.

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 10):

When you submit the page, Visualforce will update the `OwnerId` field of your opportunity object `a` automatically for you. If you want to use that value elsewhere (e.g. in a save method), you can just reference the value directly:

```
Id newApproverId = a.OwnerId;
...
```

and you can query for the corresponding name (if you need that):

```
String newApproverName = [select Name from User where Id = :a.OwnerId].Name;
...
```

Answer (score 5):

The inputfield will have a direct binding to the `a.ownerid`.

This binding is two-directional, so that means two things:

1. When the page loads, the input field will be filled with `a.ownerid`.
2. The reverse is also true: the value of the input field will be saved to `a.ownerid`. If you had a commandButton with an action that is executed on the controller, the `a.ownerid` will by then have the value that the user entered on the Visualforce page before the user clicked the commandButton.

Update your Visualforce code like so to include that commandButton

```
<apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:InputField label="user" value="{!a.ownerid}"/>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!someAction}" value="Save"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Now you can reference `a.owernid` anywhere in that `someAction` method on the controller, and use code like this to store it to owername:

```
public PageReferene someAction() {
    ownername = a.ownerid;
}
```